# Akka, syetem.actorSelection(/user/*) vs system.eventStream

Tags: scala, events, event-handling, akka, event-bus

I'm looking for a solution to send event to all actors and foudn two solutions that are perefectly acceptabel in my case.

**Solution 1**, `system.actorSelection("/user/*") ! Event`

Select all user actors and tell them the `Event`.

The pros is that the "subscribers" don't have to subscribe to anything, they only have to match the event or ignore it.

The cons is that there is no events classification but I'm not sure that I need it in my simple app. But as explained by @rethab in his comment, that will also pollute the dead letter queue.

**Solution 2**, `system.eventStream.publish(event)`

Use the Akka event bus to publish the event. Ths pros is that it exists for that. The cons is that it has classification while I'm not sure to use it.

As you can read, both are equivalents from my point of view. So what would be the best solution and why ?

Comment: It seems the issue is whether you need the bus to decouple publisher from subscriber or you are fine with the event producer knowing where it needs to go.

Comment: I want to decouple. That's why I plan to usie `actorSelection` or the `eventStream`

Comment: Two more things to consider: 1. with the event stream, you'll have to pass the sender reference along in order to reply to the message. 2. with the actorSelection, how would you "ignore" the message? if you don't handle it, it will end up in the dead letter queue and if you don't want that, you'll have to have a catch-all case (which may swallow messages and thereby errors are less obvious). --> So I would probably go for the event stream, which makes it explicit per actor which messages it wants to handle.

Comment: @rethab Thanks for your advice about the dead letter queue. It is exactly why I asked the SO community.